# Add search term to search results page

Tags: search

I'd like to include the search term on the search results page.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extra to the default search component, we have another search component
called **Smart Search**.

You can find this component in:
**Components** > **Smart Search** and
**Extensions** > **Modules** > **New** > **Smart Search**

You also have some configuration in:
**System** > **Global Configuration** > **Smart Search**

From here change to show the field **Query Explanation**, see the screenshot:

[image]

If you want to change the label, go to:
**Extensions** > **Languaje** > **Overrides** > **New**

Regards!